# How to change SelectedTabColor and UnselectedTabColor in Xamarin.Forms ( BottomBarPage )

Tags: c#, xamarin

How to change SelectedTabColor and UnselectedTabColor in Xamarin.Forms ( BottomBarPage ) - My BottomBarPage XML is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xf:BottomBarPage   
xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:BottomBar.XamarinForms; assembly=BottomBar.XamarinForms"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ECommerce.Views"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="ECommerce.Views.MainMenu"
BarBackgroundColor="White"
BarTextColor="#FF64AA"
SelectedTabColor="#FF64AA" UnselectedTabColor="Black"
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
...
```

It works in ios however not in android, help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin has not been updated for a long time (more than 2 years) . If you want to let the tabbed display in bottom of the screen , you just need to use the default **TabbedPage** and  set the value of **ToolbarPlacement** .

```
<TabbedPage ...
            
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
          
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
                 
            BarBackgroundColor="White"                 
            SelectedTabColor="#FF64AA" UnselectedTabColor="Black"           
            ...>
```

If it still doesn't work ,add the following lines in xaml

```
android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="Black"
android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#FF64AA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use TabbedPage with Android Specific Platform Configuration for Toolbar(Tab Bar) Placement on Android:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        x:Class="Test.MyTabbedPage"
        BarBackgroundColor="White"
        BarTextColor="#FF64AA"
        SelectedTabColor="#FF64AA"
        UnselectedTabColor="Black"
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```

Answer (score -1):

This could help you

```html
   <xf:BottomBarPage.ToolbarItems x:BackgroundColor="#D60000">
        <ToolbarItem Name="User" Order="Primary" Icon="home.png" Text="Item 1" Priority="0"       Clicked="User_Clicked"/>
 
    </xf:BottomBarPage.ToolbarItems>

    <xf:BottomBarPage.Children>
        <Views:MainPage 
            ClassId="Home"
            Title="Page1" 
            Icon="Page1.png" 
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
        <Views:MainPage 
            Title="Page2" 
            Icon="Page2.png"  
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
        <Views:Graphs 
            Title="Page3"  
            Icon="Page3.png" 
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
        <Views:MainPage 
            Title="Page4" 
            Icon="Page4.png"
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
        <Views:Info 
            Title="Page5" 
            Icon="Page5.png"
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
    </xf:BottomBarPage.Children>
```